# Nested ListViews in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, data-binding, listview

I  am nesting 3 listviews.
I use the itemdatabound event to find my second listview to bind to.

My question is how do I find the third listview. How do I access the itemdatabound of the second listview to then find the third control.

Hope that makes sense

Thanks

EDIT: Can someone point me to a good example or tutorial on how to do this?

Comment: Are you creating the 2nd and 3rd views dynamically, or are they all defined in the markup?

Comment: They are all defined in the markup

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to place your nested ListViews in user controls so the first listview contains user control which is built from a list view that contains a second user control that in turn contains a listview.

The disadvantage of this is that your code is then spread over 3 elements rather than just one, there are also some interesting challenges in getting the right information in the right places (communicating up and down the nested tree) - but it does allow you to deal with the event issues in a fairly straightforward manner.